# I want to add a Validation rule to prevent a date prior to todays date

Tags: sql, json, validationrules

The below is what I am supposed to do:

> Please label this field as “Date of Mailing” on the UI
>
> This field should display under Cancellation Effective Date
>
> The name should be dateOfMailing
>
> The default value should be todays date
>
> Add a validation rule to prevent a date prior to todays date (The
> cancellation effective date field has similar logic you can use as an
> exam

I am having trouble with the validation rule.

I did:

```
{
      "type": "date",
      "name": "dateOfMailing",
      "description": "Date of Mailing",
      "dataType": "string",
      "required": true,
      "format": "date",
      "width": "400",
      "emitBlur": true,
      "defaultValue": "new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]",
      "validationRule": "dateOfMailing; new Date({0}) <= new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)",
      "errorMessage": "*Date of Mailing must be today or later"
    },
```

also tried:

```
 "validationRule": "dateOfMailing; new Date({0}) < new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)",
 "validationRule": "dateOfMailing; new Date({0}) > new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)",
```

Error shows when a future date is picked.

Comment: first which database system are you using, second i have a hard time understanding what you are tying have you any try to show us

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are the values for new Date({0}) and new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I expect validationRule is defining what is acceptable. If so,
unacceptable date input should trigger errorMessage.

Rule with `<=` means input date earlier than current is acceptable and future date is not.

Change operator to `>=` as input date greater than or equal to current is valid.

```
"validationRule": "dateOfMailing; new Date({0}) >= new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)",
```

However, attempt using `>` should have allowed future date but not current.